# Distinct string count in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .tsv data file. I want to print the count of strings in a certain column. The column looks like this:

```
column1
A aaa
A, C c
C
D
E ee,F
A aaa, B, C cc
F
E ee
```

I want distinct counts of A,B,C, A aaa etc. But in the column, there are sometimes spaces after the ",". So my code counts "B" and " B" differently. This is the code I am currently using:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# Import data from file into Pandas DataFrame
data= pd.read_csv("data.tsv", encoding='utf-8', delimiter="\t")
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
out = data['Column1'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
print (out)
```

Any leads are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `' '` into your split, i.e. `split(', ')`. Try `',\s*'` for `,` followed by optional spaces:

```
out = df['column1'].str.split(',\s*', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
F        2
E ee     2
A aaa    2
C c      1
C        1
A        1
C cc     1
B        1
D        1
dtype: int64
```

Also, you can replace `', '` with `','` and use `get_dummies`:

```
df['column1'].str.replace(',\s*',',').str.get_dummies(',').sum()
```

Output:

```
A        1
A aaa    2
B        1
C        1
C c      1
C cc     1
D        1
E ee     2
F        2
dtype: int64
```